# Use open Excel file name in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have two Excel files open. I would like to create a formula that refers to the current workbook AND another open workbook. The referenced file name is not always the same and may have spaces, and will be used in a formula.

I can reference the current file name and use it in a formula with `CELL("filename")` but am not sure how reference another (not currently active) open file. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Mike Hi, sorry for the late reply. I've been on holiday.

Comment: @Mike I "solved" it with a workaround some weeks ago, but I'll give your answer a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this function in your workbook VBA.

```
Function OtherName()
    Dim wb As Workbook, x As String
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            x = wb.Name
        End If
    Next wb
    OtherName = x
End Function
```

Then you just have to call it with your code.